# Protractor Failed: element(...).sendkeys is not a function

Tags: protractor

> Protractor  Failed: element(...).sendkeys is not a function
>       isPresent method on the same input element returns true but not the sendkeys

I get this error when I run my ***conf.js***

protractor Version 5.2.2

node v8.9.4

Selenium build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b'

Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Thank you for any help in advance

Comment: Post your code. It could be something as simple as a syntax error but we will have no way to know.

Answer (score 6):

use

`element(by.css('div')).sendKeys('somekeys')`

with capitalized K instead of

`element(by.css('div')).sendkeys('somekeys')`